# How can I reverse geocode records from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, rails-geocoder

Why wouldn't

```
Location.where(address: nil).each do |location|
    location.reverse_geocode
    location.save!
end
```

work, while

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
    after_validation :reverse_geocode
end
```

reverse geocodes any new locations?
The console doesn't error, it just returns the activerecord relation with the address values still nil.

Comment: very strange! try without the bang and just `save` it. Could be that it relies on callbacks that are being skipped

Comment: Nope, no luck. Does it work for you? Could it have to do with the rails console not waiting for the response from the geocoding provider?

Comment: true. try the usual restart console, database, wait an hour try again in case you were rate limited, restart cache server if you're caching, possibly even clear your cache

Comment: Did that. No results.

Comment: Are you still calling `reverse_geocoded_by` in your model? I think you might need this in order to later call reverse_geocode.

Comment: Yep, it's still working when I submit new locations via my HTTPClient app.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this works for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my original solution worked, I just had to restart my machine. 
Strangely, restarting the console, server, and editor did nothing, so I suspect some dark magic is going on with RVM.

Thanks for the help, everyone.

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
location.address = location.reverse_geocode
location.save!
```

Comment: It started working this morning. Restarting the console didn't work, but restarting the entire machine did. Might have something to do with RVM/ my gem list. Thanks for the help.